# Starting a temporary MySQL server with Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I would like to execute a specific version of mysqld through Python for unit testing. The idea is to execute the server on a thread, test, and kill the server when it's done. (Similar to [testing.mysqld](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testing.mysqld/), which sadly doesn't work on Windows.). This is the current code:

```
    #Create a temporary folder.
    base_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    #Extract the default files
    zipfile.ZipFile(r"O:\Tools\mysql\min_mysql.zip").extractall(base_path)

    #Setup my_ini file
    my_ini_path = os.path.join(base_path, "my.ini").replace("\\", "/")
    unix_base_path = posixpath.normpath(base_path).replace("\\", "/")

    with open(my_ini_path, 'r') as my_ini:
      filedata = my_ini.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace("{{basedir}}", unix_base_path)
    with open(my_ini_path, 'w', 0) as my_ini:
      my_ini.write(filedata)

    #Open mysqld
    args = r"O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file=\"%s\"" % (my_ini_path)
    args = shlex.split(args)
    mysqld_process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
    mysqld_process.wait()
```

But if I execute it through Python, I get this error:

```
    Could not open required defaults file:
    "c:\users\pelfeli1\appdata\local\temp\tmp2vct38\my.ini"
    Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

So far I have verified that the file exists before starting the process. If I print the command verbatim and execute it, the server runs fine.

There seems to be a difference between Popen and just executing in shell. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but the `args` string shouldn't be defined as raw (with the `r`). Instead, do this: `'O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file="%s"'` (ie. use single quotes). Unless you intend to pass the backslashes to the command line

Comment: Well, this is odd. I removed the `r` and the quotes altogether. It worked. The server starts. I have no idea why, as it still works with the quotes on CMD. Man I hate that feeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll copy my comment here, if you want to accept it as an answer:

> I don't think this is the problem, but the `args` string shouldn't be
>   defined as raw (with the r). Instead, do this:
>   `'O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file="%s"'` (ie. use single
>   quotes). Unless you intend to pass the backslashes to the command line

Now, take into account that the following two strings

```
 "foo\"bar\""
r"foo\"bar\""
```

Are *not* the same. The first one renders `foo"bar"`, while the second gives you `foo\"bar\"`.

So, what was happening is that the shell sees this as the file name: `"c:\users\pelfeli1\appdata\local\temp\tmp2vct38\my.ini"`, *including* the quotes, because of the backquotes (`\`). You could have just written this:

```
args = 'O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file="%s"' % (my_ini_path)
```

just in case of spaces in `my_ini_path`, without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in the quotes. Just changed this line:

```
    args = r"O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file=\"%s\"" % (my_ini_path)
```

to this line

```
    args = "O:/Tools/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file=%s" % (my_ini_path)
```

I still have no idea why this changes anything, because printing args gives a valid (and working) command in both cases.